GSI parallel query for vertical scaling of ECS
I have an Application deployed in ECS, which query Dynamodb on the status column using GSI and perform some computations and update the status.
My problem is querying the GSI in pagination takes a long time, I want to scale application horizontally i.e increase the desired count from 1 to 5. Which will launch 5 ecs task of the same application. Doing this makes it difficult to query.
One approach I can think about is adding a sort key to gsi and adding values like 1,2,3,4,5 and then the task definition 1 will query on records with sort key 1 and so on. But the problem here is I cannot think of a query that will achieve the same.
Need help to get thing working. I am doing this in java

We have achieved this by implementing the token management system.
We added an entry in the db with the below attributes
Id: TOKEN
CurrentAvailableToken: 5
MaxToken : 5

We will make the Desired count as 5.
When task-1 runs it will get the CurrentAvailableToken as 5 and decrement and update the token as 4. task-1 will read all data with status=ACTIVE and taskNumber=5.
When task-1 runs it will get the CurrentAvailableToken as 4 and decrement and update the token as 3. task-1 will read all data with status=ACTIVE and taskNumber=4
and it continues.

A Query operation will do that no problem.
SELECT * FROM mytable.mygsi WHERE gsipk='ACTIVE' AND gsisk=1
SELECT * FROM mytable.mygsi WHERE gsipk='ACTIVE' AND gsisk=2
...
SELECT * FROM mytable.mygsi WHERE gsipk='ACTIVE' AND gsisk=N

How will i pass the N .. since the code will be same in all the deployed task defination.. how will i change the value of n in different task defination

You could pass it as parameters when launching your task. Or have them poll from a queue and acquire a value each for example.

but the same parameter will be passed to every task definition in the replica set. I want to pass different parameters for different task definitions when the application is horizontally scaling.
Also if I pool from SQS  how will I guarantee that each task definition has different N value ?

Continuously querying the DDB like that seems like a waste of money to me.
Especially if you're just basically trying to get a count of ACTIVE items.
It would probably be more cost effective to enable DDB streams + Lambda to pre-calculate that aggregation as outlined in the documentation

Using Global Secondary Indexes for materialized aggregation queries.
Build aggregations for Amazon DynamoDB tables using Amazon DynamoDB Streams


I understand that will be a good solution.. but i have requirement to solution this
